# Attribute error str object has no attribute get while submitting form

Tags: python, django, forms

This is the ObjectCreateMixin class which from which my TagCreate class inherits

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render


class ObjectCreateMixin:
    form_class = None
    template_name = ''

    def get(self, request):
        return render(
            request,
            self.template_name,
            {'form': self.form_class()})

    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_object = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_object)
        else:
            return render(
                request,
                self.template_name,
                {'form': bound_form}
            )
```

Here is My TagCreate class

```py
class TagCreate(ObjectCreateMixin, View):
    form_class = TagForm
    template_name = 'organizer/tag_form.html'
```

I am trying to create Tag object by passing the name and slug in form but whenever i submit form it gives error ATTRIBUTE error 'str' has no attribute 'get'

This is full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 142, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\suorganizer\organizer\utilis.py", line 13, in post
    if bound_form.is_valid():
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 205, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 200, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 439, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 471, in _post_clean
    exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()
  File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 422, in _get_validation_exclusions
    field_value = self.cleaned_data.get(field)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This is TagForm

```
class TagForm(SlugCleanMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = Tag
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is SlugCleanMixin class from which my TagForm class inherits

```
class SlugCleanMixin:
    def clean_slug(self):
        new_slug = (
            self.cleaned_data['slug'].lower()
        )
        if new_slug == 'create':
            raise ValidationError('Slug may not be "create" .')
        return new_slug
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do already exists. This is a [**`CreateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView). I would advise using this since this has been tested by Django developers and a lot of Django users probably found issues and fixed these.

Your [**`.clean()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method) however violates its "contract": it should return a dictionary of data, not a single element. You here only clean a single field, so you can work with:

```
class TagForm(SlugCleanMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_name(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['name'].lower()
```

for the view, you can work with:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView


class TagCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = TagForm
    template_name = 'organizer/tag_form.html'
```

Comment: so how to solve this clean method error which you are talking about

Comment: is there any error in my ObjectCreateMixin class?

Comment: what change i need to make in clean method in my TagForm please can you tell

Comment: @AmazingWriters: rename `clean` to `clean_name`.

Comment: @AmazingWriters: the `ObjectCreateMixin` is not "wrong" but mainly incomplete: it will for example not pass `request.FILES` to the form, etc.

Comment: so what is missing in ObjectCreateMixin

Comment: where i should rename clean to clean_name

Comment: Thanks Willem Van Onsem i changed the name from clean to clean_name and it worked but can you tell me why changing the name of clean to clean_name was necessary . why name clean was causing error?

Comment: @AmazingWriters: because `clean` should return a dictionary of the cleaned values, not a single one. In your `TagForm`, you only returned the lowercase of the name.

Comment: @AmazingWriters: for example passing `request.FILES` to the form. See the `get_form` method: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/